# Help identifying an elemental kids show

Tags: story-identification, tv

It was about the four elements; fire was evil, I think.

The first episode showed a pile of rocks that then formed a boy.  He went into the forest and met a water boy who has a mustache and a ponytail. Then they meet a boy with an eagle-like face who's rude and wields the power of air. None of them could remember how they got there or what had happend.

Episodes later I remember their hot air balloon crashes in the forest. The rock boy was brown, water boy was blue like he was made of water and air boy was white.

The rock boy had bright blue eyes and he was friendly
I think that water boy had red hair and he was wise I think that his name began with “J.” The show was aimed for kids I watched it when I was a kid. I think it came out between the end of 2000s and the start of 2010s.

Comment: I'm sure you can remember more. What was the kid's name? Was he caucasian or black or something else? Why did the water boy have a moustache. How old was he? What was his name? How did they wield the elements? What powers did they display? How did they get their powers? Was the show aimed at adults or kids?

Comment: Without knowing location/time, I can't say, but Malaysian cartoon BoBoiBoy has elemental boys interacting.  They're all the same person, ultimately, but...

Comment: "end of 2000s, start of 2010s" doesn't leave much wiggle room...